# how to set verticalalignment in Rich textbox

Tags: c#, richtextbox

please teach me the way to set vertical alignment in Rich textbox

i found out how to set horizen alignment in rich textbox

[Sample code]

```
richTextBox1.SelectionAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center
```

but it is not vertical alignment

i really wanna answer it from everyone

Answer (score 0):

> Flow document are designed to optimize viewing and readability. Rather
>   than being set to one predefined layout, flow documents dynamically
>   adjust and reflow their content based on tun-time variables such as
>   window size, device resolution, and optional user preferences.
>
> So, we cannot set the layout of the document in the RichTextBox
>   manually, but for the paragraph, we can set the TextAlignment
>   property. And you can also try to set the Padding property for the
>   RichTextBox to adjust it content.
>
> Hope this helps.

-- Kevin Pan

**[SOURCE LINK](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/8aaa5b74-fbc9-4b28-a423-7d1be60daca9)**

Comment: You should link to the original source.